# Issue in displaying image in Gmail body

Tags: html, email, freemarker, mime

I am trying to attach the HTML file to the Gmail body, but the image which I have attached in the HTML file is not getting displayed in Gmail (working fine in Outlook).I have tried putting the base64 code of image but still the same issue (In this case even in Outlook the image is blocked). I even tried with "Content ID generator".

Please see following code what I have tried), but unable to display image.
Can some one tell me how to solve this issue?

(Note: I have used the free marker template to generate the HTML code)

```
          Map<String, String> inlineImages = new HashMap<String, String>();

           inlineImages.put("image2", "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\Capture1.jpg");
           model.put("image", inlineImages);

            String text = geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(model);
            System.out.println("Template content : "+text);


            helper.setText(text, true);

         MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

        MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image2");
            imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            // attach the image file
            imagePart.attachFile("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\Capture1.jpg");

             multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
             mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: Google caches email images on their servers. Yours is inaccessible because it's hosted locally.

Comment: You cannot expect the user to be using windows to check their gmail messages. The path you give to the images will not match, nor display for that reason